# Concatenate BERT and CNN

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, keras-layer

I'm trying to concatenate two model in one.
I have a BERT model and EfficientNet model.

```
input_text = model_Bert.inputs[:2]
text = model_Bert(input_text)
input_img = model_EfNet.layers[0].input
img = model_EfNet(input_img)
concatenated = layers.concatenate([text, img], axis=1) #same dimension
dense = layers.Dense(512, activation='relu')(concatenated)
dense = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(dense)
dense = layers.Dropout(0.3)(dense)
outputs = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name = 'real_output')(dense)

model_Multimodal = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_text, input_img], outputs=outputs)
```

But I got this error:

---

ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
      9 outputs = layers.Dense(2, activation='softmax', name = 'real_output')(dense)
     10 
---> 11 model_Multimodal = keras.models.Model(inputs=[input_text, input_img], outputs=outputs)

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
     89                 warnings.warn('Update your `' + object_name + '` call to the ' +
     90                               'Keras 2 API: ' + signature, stacklevel=2)
---> 91             return func(*args, **kwargs)
     92         wrapper._original_function = func
     93         return wrapper

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in **init**(self, *args, **kwargs)
     92                 'inputs' in kwargs and 'outputs' in kwargs):
     93             # Graph network
---> 94             self._init_graph_network(*args, **kwargs)
     95         else:
     96             # Subclassed network

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/network.py in _init_graph_network(self, inputs, outputs, name, **kwargs)
    167                                  'must come from `keras.layers.Input`. '
    168                                  'Received: ' + str(x) +
--> 169                                  ' (missing previous layer metadata).')
    170             # Check that x is an input tensor.
    171             layer, node_index, tensor_index = x._keras_history

```
ValueError: Input tensors to a Model must come from `keras.layers.Input`. Received: [<tf.Tensor 'Input-Token_1:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=float32>, <tf.Tensor 'Input-Segment_1:0' shape=(None, 128) dtype=float32>] (missing previous layer metadata).
```

Comment: I've tried to modify the lines 2,4 like this:
`text = model_Bert.layers[105].output 
img = model_EfNet.layers[11].output`

But the error is the same.

Comment: excuse me did you solve it ?

Answer (score 1):

It is difficult to tell from your code without knowing the implementation that you're using for BERT. In particular, is it a headless model? My understanding (which could be incorrect) is that BERT without a head provides an output of shape `(batch_size, seq_length, embedding_dim)`. In other words, the output shape is variable with the input size. As such, I do not see how your image embedding will always be of the same shape as the output from your transformer.

I'm using the `transformers` [library](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers) and a pre-trained CNN to create a bimodal language model in roughly the following fashion:

```
def call(encoded_sentences, img_embeddings, **transformer_kwargs):

        outputs = transformer(encoded_sentences, **transformer_kwargs)
        last_hidden_state, *_ = outputs
        batch_size, batch_seq_len, last_hidden_dim = last_hidden_state.shape

        # reshape and repeat image embeddings
        batch_size, *img_emb_shape = img_embeddings.shape
        img_emb_flattened = tf.reshape(img_embeddings, 
                                       (batch_size, np.prod(img_emb_shape)))
        emb_flattened_reps = tf.repeat(tf.expand_dims(img_emb_flattened, 1), 
                                       batch_seq_len, axis=1)

        # concatenate the language and image embeddings
        embs_concat = tf.concat([last_hidden_state, emb_flattened_reps], 2)

        # generate mlm predictions over input sequence
        training = transformer_kwargs.get('training', False)
        prediction_scores = mlm_head(embs_concat, training=training)

        # Add hidden states and attention if they are here
        outputs = (prediction_scores,) + outputs[2:]

        return outputs
```

Where in my case, `transformer` is a `TFAlbertModel`,  `mlm_head` is a `TFAlbertMLMHead` (if this code seems a bit confusing its because I've adapted it from a class method in a `tf.keras.Model`). Also, keep in mind that the `encoded_sentences` have been passed through a tokenizer and the `img_embeddings` are extracted from a pre-trained CNN.

See [this repository](https://github.com/DylanCope/Image-Captioning-with-Bimodal-Transformers) for my notebook exploring this method for image captioning.

Comment: Now I try to explain my work: I'm trying to classify sentiment of a sentence with corresponding image. To improve my results I decide to develop three pipeline: one for only for text, one only for image and one for both.

I use all model BERT. The problem is that I can't take the output (768) of layer BERT (not the final output).
My idea is take this output, concatenate it with the output of conv layer (can be 1280 or 768) and do the classification.